# Wordpress Theme Development; Having trouble connecting 978 grid system

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am making a wordpress theme, and I am trying to base it off of a 978 grid system. I have all of the files in place, but I think something is going wrong with the link. It just shows the html now. The CSS does not even show up. That is why I think that there is a problem in the link.

I deleted this line,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

so that I could add these.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 1378px)" href="css/style/style-1378.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 1218px) and (max-width: 1377px)" href="css/style/style-1218.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 978px) and (max-width: 1217px)" href="css/style/style-978.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 748px) and (max-width: 977px)" href="css/style/style-748.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 747px)" href="css/style/style-400.css">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem exactly? Are getting any trouble in linking CSS?

Comment: this is more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this line of code and let me know .Hope it will work!

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Include above line for everylink and change you file name like style.css to style-1378.css

Answer (score 0):

For correct path it will depend on if you are using a child or parent theme

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

(for the parent template directory) or

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
```

(for the child template directory)